# How to test if HttpClient has a client certificate included?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dotnet-httpclient

I have an implementation of an authenticated `HttpClient` generator class that resembles this:

```
public class X509Authentication : IClientAuthenticator
{
    protected readonly X509Certificate2 Certificate;

    public X509Authentication(X509Certificate2 certificate)
    {
        if (certificate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("certificate");
        Certificate = certificate;
    }

    public HttpClient GenerateClient()
    {
        var clientHandler = new WebRequestHandler();
        clientHandler.ClientCertificates.Add(Certificate);
        var request = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
        return request;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //nothing to do here.
    }
}
```

... how can I test that the `GenerateClient()` method has successfully attached the client certificate to the `HttpClient` class?

```
[TestMethod]
public void HttpClientCreationIncludesCertificate()
{
    using (var auth = new X509Authentication(_certificate))
    using (var client = auth.GenerateClient())
    {
        Assert...what?  The certificate(s) are not visible here.
    }
}
```

...or am I trying to test the wrong thing?

Comment: Nobody?  Really?  I really didn't expect this to be a difficult question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9 month old question but anyhow :)

What I would do. You are thinking correctly with the interface. Now that you have an interface you can mock away the "real" implementation of `GenerateClient` since this method doesn't do anything else then using someone else's code (Code that that's not very test-friendly in the first place).

What I would test in this situation is that the method that should call `IClientAuthenticator.GenerateClient` really calls it. An example ->

```
[TestMethod]
Public void MyClass_MymethodthatcallsGenereateClient_DoesCallGenerateClient()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<IClientAuthenticator> clientAuth = new Mock<IClientAuthenticator>();
    MyClass myclass = new MyClass()

    // Act
    var result = MyClass.MymethodthatcallsGenereateClient();

    // Assert (verify that we really added the client)
    clientAuth.Verify(x => x.GenerateClient);
}
```

Now we can be safe knowing that the client certificate is added when it should be.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm... not what i wanted to test, but I guess it'll have to do.

Comment: I don't say this is the only solution but it's what I would have done for a unit test :) Another solution is integration tests where you can send a web client request and look at the response header.

Comment: Hah yeah that's less what I wanted to do.  :)